# React: Fake api's axios delete does not work

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-delete

I am practicing REST API by using one [Fake API](https://reqres.in/) site. For front-end, I am using React. I successfully login the email and password by using [Fake API](https://reqres.in/)'s login and redirect to list users, where I fetched the data from [Fake API](https://reqres.in/) and shows the user's name, image. I used the delete button where I can delete the user. I used the Axios delete method but the button does not do anything.

**This is the component**

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

    function Users() {
      const [state, setState] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        fetchingData();
      }, []);

      const removeData = id => { //THIS IS WHERE I USED THE AXIOS DELETE METHOD
        axios
          .delete(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}`)
          .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };

      const fetchingData = () => {
        axios
          .get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
          .then(response => {
            setState(response.data.data);
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col s12 m7">
            <h2 className="header">Users</h2>
            {state.map(userlist => {
              return (
                <div className="card horizontal" key={userlist.id}>
                  <div className="card-image">
                    <img src={userlist.avatar} alt="images" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-stacked">
                    <div className="card-content">
                      <p>
                        Name: {userlist.first_name} {userlist.last_name}
                      </p>
                      <p>Email: {userlist.email}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-action">
                      <button
                        className="btn delete"
                        onClick={() => removeData !== userlist.id} // THIS IS WHERE I USED THE DELETE LOGIC. 
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>

                      <NavLink
                        exact
                        to={`/api/users/${userlist.id}`}
                        className="btn edit"
                      >
                        Edit
                      </NavLink>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `delete` button's `onClick` prop, you should pass the `id` as an argument.

```
 const removeData = async id => {
        console.log("ID", id);
        try {
          const response = await axios.delete(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}`);
          console.log(response);
          fetchingData();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
```

```
<button
  className="btn delete"
  onClick={() => removeData(userlist.id)} // THIS IS WHERE I USED THE DELETE LOGIC.
>
  Delete
</button>;
```

Comment: Thanks man! The results show on console but the user profile does not disappear.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I noticed that too. Even though the `API` response is correct, they are not deleting the user.

Comment: Is there any solution?  I found one [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mohsen1932/reactjs-reqres.in) where the user can delete the data and user profile can also disappear.

Comment: Let me check the repo.